# Is there a way to filter with JPA using a Set of IDs?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

```
public class ProcessEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String processDefinitionName;
    @Column(name = "groups_ids")
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Long> groupIdsProcess = new HashSet<>();
}

public class ProcessInstance implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private ProcessEntity processEntity;
}
```

I want to filter ProcessInstance using JPA by using a method like:

```
List<ProcessInstance> getAllByProcessEntityGroupIdsProcessContains(Set<Long> setOfIDs)
```

That will return a list of `ProcessInstances` whose `processEntity.groupIdsProcess` contains any of the IDs contained in the passed parameter `Set<Long> setOfIDs`

Is it possible?

I tried writing a native query without success, help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a JPA find method, for your example:

```
findAllByProcessEntity_GroupIdsProcessIsIn(Set<Long> setOfIDs)
```

I am not sure about the groupIdsProcess part, that is annotated with @ElementCollection, but missing a @CollectionTable(...) annotation, does it correctly map and return every value if you use findAll() in the ProcessInstance Repository?