# Filter data with JPA Specification using a Set of IDs as a parameter?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa

```
public class ProcessEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String processDefinitionName;
    @Column(name = "groups_ids")
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Long> groupIdsProcess = new HashSet<>();
}

public class ProcessInstance implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private ProcessEntity processEntity;
}
```

I want to filter `ProcessInstance` using a Specification that will return a list of `ProcessInstance` whose `processEntity.groupIdsProcess` contains any of the IDs contained in the passed parameter `Set<Long> setOfIDs`

I've tried using Join<ProcessInstance, ProcessEntity> without success.

Is it possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday and got an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76315446/is-there-a-way-to-filter-with-jpa-using-a-set-of-ids?rq=2

Comment: no, that was using a plain repository method, I wanted to see if it was possible or not in case the Specification route would fail, but I have to use a Specification because I got a ton of optional fields I have to filter the data with like name, date, ownerName, etc so a Specification would make more sense considering those fields are optional, but the groupIds filtering is obligatory.